# Getting Multiple active links in a Bootstrap List-group Navigation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a page navigation list-group using bootstrap.

When a user clicks on a new link in the list-group, the active status must be removed from the previous link and placed on the new link.

The problem is the the blue active link is not being removed from the previous link and this creates multiple blue active links at the same time, like you see in the picture. I would like to see only one blue active link at the same time.

[image]

Could you help me spot the problem with my code?

Thanks!

The code:

```html
<!-- List group -->
<ul class="list-group" id="myList" role="tablist">
  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" data-toggle="list" href="#home" role="tab">Home</li>
  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="list" href="#profile" role="tab">Profile</li>
  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="list" href="#messages" role="tab">Messages</li>
  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="list" href="#settings" role="tab">Settings</li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home" role="tabpanel">A</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile" role="tabpanel">B</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages" role="tabpanel">C</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings" role="tabpanel">D</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap has in-built [`navs`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navs/#javascript-behavior) that takes care of this. So there is no need to use `list-group` with custom javascript.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Home</a>
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#profile">Profile</a>
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#messages">Messages</a>
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#settings">Settings</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-9">
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home">A</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">B</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="messages">C</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="settings">D</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

So, when you fire `click` event loop through the other `li` elements and remove the `active` class, then add the `active` class the clicked `li` item, same with `tabs`

```js
const lis = document.querySelectorAll('.list-group-item');
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-pane');

lis.forEach(li => {
  li.addEventListener('click', () => {
    lis.forEach(li => li.classList.remove('active'));
    li.classList.add('active');
    const targetTab = document.querySelector(li.getAttribute('href'));
    tabs.forEach(tab => tab.classList.remove('active'));
    targetTab.classList.add('active');
  })
})
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!-- List group -->
<ul class="list-group" id="myList" role="tablist">
  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" data-toggle="list" href="#home" role="tab">Home</li>
  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="list" href="#profile" role="tab">Profile</li>
  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="list" href="#messages" role="tab">Messages</li>
  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="list" href="#settings" role="tab">Settings</li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home" role="tabpanel">A</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile" role="tabpanel">B</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages" role="tabpanel">C</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings" role="tabpanel">D</div>
</div>
```